# Laravel 5 WithInput error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

estoy intentando que al haber un error en el formulario de login me retorne a la vista registro manteniendo los datos en el formulario. con un return back()->withInput y me hace el return correctamente pero no me muestra mis datos aqui esta el codigo:

RegistroController:

```
public function showRegistro()
{
    return view('registro');
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->password1 != $request->password2) {
        //return back()->withInput();
        return back()->withInput($request->input());


    } else {
        $usuario = new User();
        $usuario->nombre = $request->nombre;
        $usuario->email = $request->input('email');
        $usuario->direccion = $request->input('direccion');
        $usuario->password = $request->input('password1');
        $usuario->id_rol = 2; 
    }



    try {
        $usuario->save();
        }   catch (QueryException $e){
        session(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
```

```
@extends('layouts.principal')

@section('titulo')
Registro
@endsection


@section('principal')
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h3 class="panel-title">Registro de usuario</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
      {{ Form::open(['action' => 'RegistroController@register', 'method' =>        'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) }}
<div class="form-group">
       {{-- {{ Form::label('nombre', 'Nombre', ['class' => 'col-sm-2    control-label']) }} --}}
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">E-mail</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
       </div>
        </div>
           <div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputDireccion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Direccion</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion" name="direccion" placeholder="Direccion">
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Contraseña</label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" name="password1" placeholder="Contraseña">
     </div>
        </div>
              <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Confirmar Contraseña</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2"    name="password2" placeholder="Confirmar Contraseña">
      </div>
     </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Aceptar</button>
             </div>
                 </div>
     @endsection
```

Gracias de Antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta en tu vista poner tus campos inputs el atributo value de esta manera:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="{{ old("nombre") }}">
```

En este caso es **"nombre"** es el mismo valor que tiene el atributo name.

De esta manera puedes tener el campo con el valor viejo o sea el redireccionado de sde tu controladora con **back()->withInput($request->input())**

Comment: Muchas Gracias me faltaba añadir el campo value="{{ old("nombre") en el formulario ya funciona

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta que estás utilizando el form builder de Laravel Collective, no es necesario agregar el helper `old()` como lo sugiere la otra respuesta, puedes hacer esto:

```
{!! Form::password('password1', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Contraseña']) !!}
```

---

Sin embargo, realizar la validación de la forma que lo haces no es el método recomendado, lo que deberías hacer es utilizar los métodos y reglas de validación de Laravel, en el caso de la confirmación de clave utilizarías la regla `confirmed`, en la cual el primer campo se llamaría por ejemplo `password` y el segundo `password_confirmation`.

Por favor revisa la documentación de Laravel sobre cómo realizar las validaciones y sus respectivas reglas:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-confirmed